# Mysql Server keeps resetting root and user passwords after reboot

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

This happens every time I reboot. Tried resetting passwords using `--init-file` but it didn't help. Only solution I found was to reinstall a brand new instance and setup the databases again.

Been experiencing it on different versions of MySQL. At the minute I'm on 5.7.

Comment: does it reset to default or it removes the passwords?

Comment: Actually just figured it out, when I was making a dump of the production databases `mysqldump --all-databases` command also brings all the internal databases like `mysql` and the tables inside of that `mysql`.`user` which contain all passwords and it also brings through all privileges from the production environment. So when I reboot, mysql server also restarts and `privileges are flushed` making all passwords change to production passwords. Should at least give an option to leave those out and not assume I want to export them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually just figured it out, when I was making a dump of the production databases `mysqldump --all-databases` command also brings all the internal databases like `mysql` and the tables inside of that `mysql`.`user` which contain all passwords and it also brings through all privileges from the production environment. So when I reboot, mysql server also restarts and `privileges are flushed` making all passwords change to production passwords. Should at least give an option to leave those out and not assume I want to export them.

Leaving this on here for whoever else might run into this issue.